# AngularJS - ngOptions sort numerically by label

Tags: angularjs

I have users upload tabular data, then I allow them to parse it before it gets inserted all the way.

For example one user may upload:

```
ID, NAME, PASSWORD, ADDRESS, EMAIL
10, Tim, foo, 123 S Main, tim@mailinator.com
11, Withers, foo, 123 S Main, tim@mailinator.com
//ETC//
```

And another user may format their data differently:

```
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ID, PASSWORD, EMAIL
Tim, Withers, 10, 123, tim@mailinator.com
//You get the idea...
```

My app takes the data and allows the user to specify which columns have the necessary information before the final upload to the server:

```
Column 0 => ID
Column 4 => Email
Column 2 => Password
```

I would like to use a `select` to limit user input:

```
Which column is the First Name? 
<select 
    ng-options="k as k for (k,v) in uploadData.row[0]" 
    ng-model="columnData.firstName">
</select>
```

This works great, but if they have more than 9 columns the select box looks like this:

```
0
1
10
11
12
13
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

How do I make sure that it is displayed 1-13 consecutively?  Is there another way to create a select with options for a specific length?

**EDIT:** Fiddle with problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/204/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly OK to use ng-repeat over `option` tag to generate options for a select box.
Using `ngRepeat`there are at least two ways to meet your requirements.

#### Using `(key, value) in expression`

```html
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option ng-repeat="(key, friend) in friends" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

#### Using `$index` property of ngRepeat iterator

```html
<select ng-model="selected">
  <option ng-repeat="friend in friends" value="{{$index}}">{{$index}}</option>
</select>
```

Since `ngRepeat` iterator is zero-based, these two examples will produce options in range 0-12. To make it display options 1-13 you can simply add `+1`on each iteration:

```html
<option ng-repeat="(key, friend) in friends" value="{{key+1}}">{{key+1}}</option>
```

or

```html
<option ng-repeat="friend in friends" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
```

Comment: Simple.  I am hitting my head now as to why I didn't just do this in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

[The angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) explains that the comprehension expression you are using (`label for (key , value) in object`) applies to object data sources. This is why it is handling indexes as strings rather than ints.

You should try using index of:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="friends.indexOf(v) for v in friends">
```

[Here is your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/207/)

Comment: I like this, and it is what I was looking for, but I decided to go with the ng-repeat using the option instead of using ng-options.  Great answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You need a filter to sort them.  I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp4zA/).

The `ng-options` is now:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="id for id in friends|sortKeyIds"></select>
```

And I added the filter (I had to put your controller in a module to add the filter).  I'm sure there's better ways to do this key extraction and filtering (I would have used underscore.js if I wasn't stuck in the fiddle).

```
app.filter('sortKeyIds', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var keys = angular.forEach(input, function(value, key) {
            return parseInt(key);
        });
        keys.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
        return keys;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.  It just wasn't the route I was looking to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use existing filter itself to sort by integer as given below using parseInt .

```
ng-options="o as o.id  for o in products | orderBy:'parseInt(id)' track by o.id"
```